# How to add parsys in custom react component programatically?

Tags: reactjs, aem, single-page-application

I am trying to create a custom component in AEM's SPA editor for react. The custom component  will only hold a parsys or a responsive-grid, where i can drag and drop components.
I can do it very easily in htl :
`<sly data-sly-resource="${'parsys' @ resourceType='foundation/components/parsys'}"></sly>`

How can I implement it in react?

Adobe's [reference implementation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/sites/using/getting-started-spa-wknd-tutorial-develop/react.html) doesn't provide any solution for this though it provides Layout Container. I've gone through adobe's example and many others on internet, also checked the [adobe experience league](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/), but nothing useful found so far.

Any idea or solution would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls let me know if you have found any solutions so far...